# How to redirect after signing up in django all auth?

Tags: django

I am signing up using django allauth but after signup it automatically redirect to user's profile page but insted of that i want to redirect user to confirmation email sent page...can any one help me to do so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following settings should be what you need

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'  # Or whatever you want to redirect to after email verification
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'   # This will force verification
```

There are other settings, but this is what you need to ensure verification is required before users are allowed to login

Comment: but after new user sign up it must goes to email confirmation sent template how can i do that if i do 'LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL'='/' then it redirect to http://localhost:8000

Comment: please help me to do so

Comment: Did you try the options above? Please show the settings you are currently using

Comment: well..okay by using above setting it works thanks aalot for the help:)

Answer (score 1):

**Just in your settings.py**

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_REDIRECT_URL = "/profile/"
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way for me to this dynamically. That is, depending on where the user was coming from when they entered the sign-up flow send it there? I have been trying to do this by adding informations to the request but after the user is headed to google I loses all states